# Vlookup in Pandas for specific column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, vlookup

I am facing some difficulties using merge function in Pandas. I am looking for some kind of Vlookup formula for this. However, I couldn't solve my problem.

My data is huge and I couldn't share here due to confidentiality. However, I try to came up with similar data here.

| Old Code | New Code | Name | Invoice Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1001011 | NA | Cheese Cake | 02/02/2021 |
| 1001012 | NA | Coffee | 03/05/2021 |
| 1001011 | NA | Cheese Cake | 30/05/2021 |
| NA | 2002093 | Jasmine Tea | 21/08/2021 |
| NA | 2002042 | Cookies | 31/12/2021 |
| NA | 2002080 | Coffee | 09/01/2022 |
| NA | 2002093 | Jasmine Tea | 05/05/2022 |
| NA | 2002058 | Cheese Cake | 07/06/2022 |

I would like to have a COST Column input in my table above. However, the cost is very by invoice date (Also take note on the changing of product code). We have 2 cost table.
For year 2021:

| Old Code | New Code | Name | Jan-21 | Feb-21 | Mar-21 | Apr-21 | May-21 | June-21 | Jul-21 | Aug-21 | Sep-21 | Oct-21 | Nov-21 | Dec-21 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1001011 | 2002058 | Cheese Cake | 50 | 51 | 50 | 53 | 54 | 52 | 55 | 53 | 50 | 52 | 53 | 53 |
| 1001012 | 2002080 | Coffee | 5 | 6 | 5 | 6 | 6 | 5 | 7 | 5 | 6 | 5 | 6 | 6 |
| 1001015 | 2002093 | Jasmine Tea | 4 | 3 | 3 | 4 | 4 | 3 | 5 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 4 |
| 1001020 | 2002042 | Cookies | 20 | 20 | 21 | 20 | 22 | 20 | 21 | 20 | 22 | 20 | 21 | 22 |

And also for Year 2022:

| Old Code | New Code | Name | Jan-22 | Feb-22 | Mar-22 | Apr-22 | May-22 | June-22 | Jul-22 | Aug-22 | Sep-22 | Oct-22 | Nov-22 | Dec-22 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1001011 | 2002058 | Cheese Cake | 52 | 52 | 55 | 55 | 56 | 52 | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA |
| 1001012 | 2002080 | Coffee | 5 | 6 | 5 | 6 | 6 | 6.5 | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA |
| 1001015 | 2002093 | Jasmine Tea | 4 | 3 | 3 | 5 | 5 | 5.5 | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA |
| 1001020 | 2002042 | Cookies | 22 | 22 | 23 | 23 | 23.5 | 23 | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA |

So basically, I would like to have my cost column in my first Data Frame to reflect the correct costing for different Year and different Month.

Example:

Invoice Date Costing for 03/05/2021 = May_2021

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have the month and code number on both sides when merging, so:

1. Create a year-month column in the invoice dataframe that is consistent with the cost table
2. Combine two cost tables
3. Merge with new code and old code respectively

```
import pandas as pd
import io
import datetime

invoice_data_text = '''Old Code New Code    Name    Invoice Date
1001011 NA  Cheese Cake 02/02/2021
1001012 NA  Coffee  03/05/2021
1001011 NA  Cheese Cake 30/05/2021
NA  2002093 Jasmine Tea 21/08/2021
NA  2002042 Cookies 31/12/2021
NA  2002080 Coffee  09/01/2022
NA  2002093 Jasmine Tea 05/05/2022
NA  2002058 Cheese Cake 07/06/2022
'''

cost_2021_text = '''
Old Code    New Code    Name    Jan-21  Feb-21  Mar-21  Apr-21  May-21  June-21 Jul-21  Aug-21  Sep-21  Oct-21  Nov-21  Dec-21
1001011 2002058 Cheese Cake 50  51  50  53  54  52  55  53  50  52  53  53
1001012 2002080 Coffee  5   6   5   6   6   5   7   5   6   5   6   6
1001015 2002093 Jasmine Tea 4   3   3   4   4   3   5   3   3   3   3   4
1001020 2002042 Cookies 20  20  21  20  22  20  21  20  22  20  21  22
'''

cost_2022_text = '''
Old Code    New Code    Name    Jan-22  Feb-22  Mar-22  Apr-22  May-22  June-22 Jul-22  Aug-22  Sep-22  Oct-22  Nov-22  Dec-22
1001011 2002058 Cheese Cake 52  52  55  55  56  52  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
1001012 2002080 Coffee  5   6   5   6   6   6.5 NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
1001015 2002093 Jasmine Tea 4   3   3   5   5   5.5 NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
1001020 2002042 Cookies 22  22  23  23  23.5    23  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
'''

# Prepare
invoice_df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(invoice_data_text),sep="\t",parse_dates=["Invoice Date"])
cost21 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(cost_2021_text),sep='\t')
cost22 =  pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(cost_2022_text),sep='\t')

# Create Month column for merging
invoice_df["Month"] = invoice_df["Invoice Date"].map(lambda x:datetime.datetime.strftime(x,"%b-%y"))

# Combine two cost tables
cost21_stack = cost21.set_index(list(cost21.columns[:3])).stack().reset_index(name="Cost")
cost22_stack = cost22.set_index(list(cost22.columns[:3])).stack().reset_index(name="Cost")
cost_table = pd.concat([cost21_stack,cost22_stack]).rename({"level_3":"Month"},axis=1)

# Merge with new code and old code respectively
old_code_result = pd.merge(invoice_df[pd.isna(invoice_df["Old Code"]) == False], cost_table[["Old Code","Month","Cost"]], on=["Old Code","Month"] ,how="left")
new_code_result = pd.merge(invoice_df[pd.isna(invoice_df["New Code"]) == False], cost_table[["New Code","Month","Cost"]], on=["New Code","Month"] ,how="left")

# Combine result
pd.concat([old_code_result,new_code_result])
```